# Magento: Decimal Price in spanish language display Dot instead comma

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

i have multilanguage store.  default language is english.  there are few products have decimal price.

when i switch languge to spanish the comma appears instead dot in decimal price.

for example:  price: 1.35$   in english when i switch language to spanish the price will look like   Price:  1,35$

i really wanna remove this , need .   how to do that.?

Comment: this has been asked and answered many time: search how to solve it and if you have a specific question come back here

Comment: Honestly, I've been looking around google for quite some time untill I actually searched replace dot with comma. I was always trying to fiddle with the format instead of just symbols.

I'm gratefull I found this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try to change the local settings. So go to your magento directory and open the file lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml (replace en.xml by the language file for which you would like to perform your changes).

Search for

```
<numbers>
    <symbols>
        <decimal>.</decimal>
        <group>,</group>
```

Clear the cache, also for safer side please try to do this first on your test installation to avoid issues.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your locale setting

here is example for English. For that you have to do Minor changes in your Language File. >Following is the Directory Structure of File.

> => root/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml (For English Language)
>   => around line 2611 you can see following code.

```
> <currencyFormat>
>      <pattern>¤#,##0.00;(¤#,##0.00)</pattern>
> </currencyFormat>
```

=> Now Change above code with Following code.

```
>  <currencyFormat>
>       <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤;(#,##0.00 ¤)</pattern>
> </currencyFormat>
```

you can set it to for Dutch.

To fix the comma form 1.000 to 1,000

add to the past post the following :

go to:  => root/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/XX.xml (XX.xml For your Language)
for example : => root/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml (For English Language)

around line 2286 you can see following code :

```
<numbers>
    <defaultNumberingSystem> xxx your Language xxx </defaultNumberingSystem>
    <symbols>
        <decimal>,</decimal>
        <group>.</group>
```

to :

```
<numbers>
    <defaultNumberingSystem> xxx your Language xxx </defaultNumberingSystem>
    <symbols>
        <decimal>.</decimal>
        <group>,</group>
```

this wil change the comma form 1.000 to 1,000

thanks & regards

Bahattab