# Magento 1.9 string replace in grid

Tags: magento

I have made a custom grid where i have an overview in columns of prices, discounts and amounts. The decimals are separated by a dot (32.400).

What is the best way to change the dot to a comma (32,400).

I have tried the properties (price, number, currency) but these doesn't change de dot.

SAMPLE:

```
$this->addColumn('price_total', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Total'),
        'type'   => 'price',
        'index'  => 'Total'
    ));
```

EDIT:

Thank you Sunil, with your help i figured it out!
Here is how i did it, if someone might be interested.

My class in (app/code/local/SML/Exportorders/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php) Grid.php

```
class SML_Exportorders_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setId('sml_order_grid');
    $this->setDefaultSort('increment_id');
    $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{...
```

Defining column:

```
$this->addColumn('sub_total', array(
        'header' => $helper->__('Sub Total'),
        'type'   => 'text',
        'index'  => 'SubTotal',
        'renderer' => 'sml_exportorders/adminhtml_sales_order_renderer_replace'
    ));
```

Then i created a renderer file as suggested by Sunil.

app/code/local/SML/Exportorders/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Renderer/Replace.php

```
class SML_Exportorders_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Renderer_Replace extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract {
public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
$value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());

return str_replace('.', ',', $value);

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radia, please check following link of mine for options

[Magento: Decimal Price in spanish language display Dot instead comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270992/magento-decimal-price-in-spanish-language-display-dot-instead-comma/19273947#19273947)

this will change the . to , everywhere on the website, if needed only for this particular column you can use

```
str_replace(',', '.', $form);
```

in the renderer of the output

Comment: I wanted this only for my custom grid and not the whole store. So i made a renderer as you suggested. I have edited my question with the answer.
Thank you Sunil.